# FF not auto scrolling textarea

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a textarea that, when you fill a couple lines and still continue typing, does not automatically scroll down so you can see what you are typing. This is only a Firefox issue. Here is the CSS and textarea HTML:

```
#msg {
  width: 380px;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
}

<textarea id="msg" rows=2></textarea>
```

"overflow:hidden" is there because I don't want a scrollbar. Adding "cols" to the textarea makes no difference.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why would it scroll down when you told it everything that overflows should be hidden?

Comment: This seems to be the standard way to remove the scrollbar. I don't want the scrollbar there. Non-Firefox browsers scroll just fine. The cursor is always in the visible area.

Comment: Seems like you're stuck then. FF behaviour sounds correct to me, even if other browsers implement this differently.

Comment: No way to have a textarea without scrollbars that keeps the cursor visible?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of one workaround for this, and it is just an idea yet.

On the `onkeydown` event of the textarea, if you do `element.scrollTop=element.scrollHeight`, it will always scroll to the bottom of the textarea. You have to find a way to scroll to the caret position instead of the bottom (in case they are editing text not in the bottom), and you're done.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. And afraid of.

Comment: You might have to keep the scrollbar instead... Or just displaying it in FF, but it sounds crazy.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` is probably the source of your problems, take it out.